# Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Handler already set!)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I went to open a repo using Vs Code on a remote ssh host. I can ssh in successfully but when I try to open a repo I get Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Handler already set!). I've tried un installing and re installing Vs Code. Does anyone have a fix other than switching ides.

Comment: this happened to me after updating Vs Code to their latest version

Answer (score 7):

[avenmore comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126339#issuecomment-862669116) helped me:

> I started getting this message with v1.57.0 when trying to run a Vue
> project. Long story short: I usually have my DEBUG CONSOLE window
> docked inside to the right of my TERMINAL (powershell), and upon
> opening VSCode it wouldn't be visible and I'd get this message after
> building successfully and trying to launch. The work-around is to
> close VSCode, navigate to folder
> USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage and delete the
> contents (notably state.vscdb) and then restart VSCode. The DEBUG
> CONSOLE then shows itself again and all is fine unless I dock it again
> and close VSCode and there is a good chance of it happening again next
> time VSCode is opened. I have stopped docking the window inside the
> terminal and it hasn't happened since.

Comment: Worked for me. There were a couple dozen GUID-named folders within the workspaceStorage folder listed by OP. Deleting all of those cleared this error for me.

Comment: In Windows 11 worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me what solved this was to go into the 'remote explorer' and clear out the SSH Targets that I already had in there before the upgrade, and then just paste them in again. Now I can connect. For example, a re-pasted SSH command looked like:

```
 ssh -i "/Users/myuseraccount/abc.pem" someuser@ec2-ip-instance1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

A few days later this stopped working again. I think maybe because my SSH targets config saved what I pasted in as my SSH connection command. It appears "sometimes" if there are any entries in the SSH target config file, that this error occurs.

I find to ensure this error never occurs do

```
  rm ~/.ssh/config
```

every time before you open Vs Code. Assuming ~/.ssh/config is where your Vs Code is reading its SSH entries from. There is one other place possible under /etc/$somewhere (I dont know where).

Then when you go to your empty SSH Target and hit the (+) button to connect, paste in the entire ssh connection request at the top of this file. I think you have to clear out the SSH targets every time otherwise I get this error coming up again days later.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I tried removing them then adding them again like you said but I'm still getting the error

Comment: it looks like this only worked temporarily for me. today, I can still connect, and us Vs Code's terminal but when I go to 'open folder' so I can use the UI, I am getting the same "Handler already set!" error. again. I tried rebooting my instance and connecting again. but no use. I also tried clearing out my entries in ~/.ssh/config - rebooting Vs Code. and then trying again. Still not working. Then I cleared it all out again and 'pasted in the entire command to connect' with an empty SSH Target and it works again. I think the story is the 'SSH target config' - once set will fail. so paste in

Answer (score 1):

Try in settings.json add item "security.workspace.trust.enabled": false

Answer (score 0):

Windows, VSCode 1.57.1

I've just remove and added the host again in ssh configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried all solution on this post, and can't get success. Then cloned another repo on my WSL folder then open, it was fine. So I changed my repo name, then problem gone. Maybe it may dumb solution. But it works me.

Answer (score 0):

You gonna have to change the "debug.terminal.clearBeforeReusing" to true on setting.json. It works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there was a workspace folder in the folder above, deleted that and it resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

On the remote system, after various things had happened, I did `mv .vscode .vscode-old` to basically reset the remote `.vscode` (over ssh).  I had also renamed the remote folder for the project -- not sure if that matters.  Then I was was able to connect to it again.

I can't be scientific about those "various things that happened", but I'll to list some:

- I had created a second project alongside the first and had connected to it - this was for unrelated reasons and preceded the "handler" error
- it was then that I had issues connecting to the first one, even though it had worked for months and months without me ever having this `Handler already set error` -- related to creating the 2nd one?  Not sure.  The 2nd one worked fine throughout.
- I tried `File: Open Folder...` from the second remote project and opened the first; it opened but got 2 python exception errors in a python extension - unfortunately I can't remember what they were. This could be noise / unrelated.  I happen to have both MS python and pylance extensions installed remotely, I think it was the pylance once that was not happy.

  - during this, I had also renamed the 1st folder which didn't work; I'm not sure if the rename triggered the different behaviour ie python ext errors instead of the "handler" error
- I then replaced `.vscode` in the first remote project (with the new folder name)
- ... and that was when it worked, with no "handler" error and no complaints from the python extension(s)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MacOS, I found a way.

Close Visual Studio Code, delete files in these two folder, then restart Visual Studio Code.

```
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code
rm -rf $HOME/.vscode
```

Comment: Note that **all local settings** will be lost (extensions, shortcuts, etc...) with this solution.

Comment: Yup, this works but kills EVERYTHING.